# Updating null value will split row in file Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a colleague that tells me that the reason why we add `default` values instead of `null` values to our table is, that Postgresql allocates a number of bytes to a file when a new row is stored. And if this column gets updated later on, it might end up splitting this row into two rows in the file, and multiple IO operations will have to occure when reading and writing.

I'm not a Postgresql expert at all, and I have hard time finding any documentation suggesting this.
Can someone clearify this for me?
Is this a good reason for not having `null` values in a column, and using some `default` instead? Will there be any hughe performance issues in such cases?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'd say the documentation is hard to find:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/storage-file-layout.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html

It's fair to say there is a lot to absorb though.

So, the reason you SHOULD have defaults rather than NULLs is because you don't want to have an "unknown" in your column. Start with the requirements before worrying about efficiency tweaks.

Whether a particular value is null is stored in a bitmap. This bitmap is optional - so if there are no nulls in a row then the bitmap is not created. So - that suggests nulls would make a row bigger. But wait, if a bit is set to show null then you don't need the overhead of of the value structure, and (IIRC - you'll need to check the docs) that can end up saving you space. There is a good chance that general per-row overheads and type alignment issues are far more important to you though.

However - all of this is ignoring the elephant<sup>*</sup> in the room which is that if you update a row then PostgreSQL marks the current version of the row as expired and creates a whole new row. So the whole description of how updates work is just confused in that first paragraph you wrote.

So - don't worry about the efficiency of nulls in 99.9% of cases. Worry about using them properly and about the general structure of your database, its indexes and queries.

<sup>*</sup> no I'm not apologising for that pun.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It was probably me searching for the wrong terms, that ended up giving me some weird search result. 

The column is just a string value; we are not expecting it to be something specific. But instead of having `null` in the column when nothing is inserted, we have introduced a `default` value, which acts as `null` throughout the system, which I find wrong.

And that was the part that triggered me for this question, as his explanation was that it was for handling "splitting the row in the file".